# Mod_wsgi pylons (ckan) installation not working

Tags: python, apache, apache2, pylons, mod-wsgi

I am setting up CKAN, a pylons application according to these instructions:
http://packages.python.org/ckan/deployment.html

But when I point to the server (no DNS setup yet) using IP or hostname, I only see apache's greeting page, sugesting the ckan app is not being loaded.

here is my mod_wsgi script:

```
import os
instance_dir = '/home/flavio/var/srvc/ckan.emap.fgv.br'
config_file = 'ckan.emap.fgv.br.ini'
pyenv_bin_dir = os.path.join(instance_dir, 'pyenv', 'bin')
activate_this = os.path.join(pyenv_bin_dir, 'activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
from paste.deploy import loadapp
config_filepath = os.path.join(instance_dir, config_file)
from paste.script.util.logging_config import fileConfig
fileConfig(config_filepath)
application = loadapp('config:%s' % config_filepath)
```

here is my virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName dck093

ServerAlias dck093

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/flavio/var/srvc/ckan.emap.fgv.br/pyenv/bin/ckan.emap.fgv.br.py
# pass authorization info on (needed for rest api)
WSGIPassAuthorization On

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ckan.emap.fgv.br.error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ckan.emap.fgv.br.custom.log combined
<Directory /home/flavio/var/srvc/ckan.emap.fgv.br/pyenv/bin>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I try to disable the 000-default site (with a2dissite), but that dind't help.After doing this I get an Internal server error page. After a fixing some permissions I managed to get this Pylons error log:

```
sudo tail /var/log/apache2/ckan.emap.fgv.br.error.log 
[Wed Mar 30 12:38:32 2011] [error] [client 10.250.48.110]     app_iter = self.application(environ, start_response)
[Wed Mar 30 12:38:32 2011] [error] [client 10.250.48.110]   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/repoze/who/middleware.py", line 107, in __call__
[Wed Mar 30 12:38:32 2011] [error] [client 10.250.48.110]     app_iter = app(environ, wrapper.wrap_start_response)
[Wed Mar 30 12:38:32 2011] [error] [client 10.250.48.110]   File "/home/flavio/var/srvc/ckan.emap.fgv.br/pyenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pylons/middleware.py", line 201, in __call__
[Wed Mar 30 12:38:32 2011] [error] [client 10.250.48.110]     self.app, environ, catch_exc_info=True)
[Wed Mar 30 12:38:32 2011] [error] [client 10.250.48.110]   File "/home/flavio/var/srvc/ckan.emap.fgv.br/pyenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pylons/util.py", line 94, in call_wsgi_application
[Wed Mar 30 12:38:32 2011] [error] [client 10.250.48.110]     app_iter = application(environ, start_response)
[Wed Mar 30 12:38:32 2011] [error] [client 10.250.48.110]   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/weberror/evalexception.py", line 226, in __call__
[Wed Mar 30 12:38:32 2011] [error] [client 10.250.48.110]     "The EvalException middleware is not usable in a "
[Wed Mar 30 12:38:32 2011] [error] [client 10.250.48.110] AssertionError: The EvalException middleware is not usable in a multi-process environment
```

Can anyone point out what am I missing?

Comment: A log of the apache error log would be helpful

Comment: Did you try to fully specify the server name?

Comment: No log entries have been produced, and yes I fully specified the server name

Comment: I assume that the path to the wsgi script is the following:
/home/flavio/var/srvc/ckan.emap.fgv.br/pyenv/bin/ckan.emap.fgv.br.py
and that the server has full access to the script. Apologies if it sounds trivial but there are few infos :D

Comment: Yes, I double checked that ther is no typo in the path and the even chmodded the script to 777 to eliminate any permission issues.

Comment: granted access to the upper directories as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you're deploying on apache, ensure that you are not in interactive debug mode - which uses EvalException. In your Pylons config file (ckan.emap.fgv.br.ini) ensure you have this:

```
[app:main]
set debug = false
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to see exception's stacktraces in apache log, when debug is disabled? See my answer/question below.

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that you cannot use name based virtual hosts in Apache without having a hostname in DNS or local /etc/hosts which resolves to the IP of the server Apache is running on.

The second problem is because EvalException cannot be used in a multi process server configuration. Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Browser_Based_Debugger

Either disable EvalException or configure mod_wsgi such that you are using daemon mode with 'default' of a single process (don't use processes=1).

For background on various process/thread configurations possible for Apache/mod_wsgi read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading

You want to use one whereby 'wsgi.multiprocess' is False.

Comment: I actually just set debug=false in the ckan ini file and it is now working.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on the ''paste'' environment, but shouldn't be:

```
from paste.deploy.loadwsgi import loadapp
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that in production debug should be disabled, but I would really like to see stacktraces of exceptions.

Right now if I get 500 Server error inside CKAN (nice CKAN page with error info is shown) in logs I can find only error description with no stacktrace:

`[Thu Feb 12 17:04:55.037785 2015] [:error] [pid 15293:tid 139979468994304] [remote 89.71.231.138:5513] Error - <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Is there a way to enable full stacktrace with debug = false.